# Can't pass multer fileFilter error to express

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, router, multer

I'm trying uploading with multer.

I created an extra file for this and here is the fileUpload file:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const { join, extname } = require("path");

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, join(__dirname, "../public/Uploads"));
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `${uuidv4()}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
  },
});

const uploadFile = multer({
  storage: fileStorage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
      req.fileValidationError = "نوع فایل مورد قبول نیست!";
      return cb(new Error("نوع فایل درست نیست"), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
  },
});

module.exports = uploadFile;
```

And I want to pass an error when file extension doesn't match my expectation but i can't pass the error to express.
Here is my router:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const ProfilePicture = require("../models/profilePicture");
const { join, extname } = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const upload = require("../tools/fileUpload");

router.post(
  "/changeProfile",
  upload.single("profile_pic"),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { image } = await ProfilePicture.findOne({});
      await fs.unlink(join(__dirname, `../public/Uploads/${image}`), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      });

      await ProfilePicture.deleteMany();

      await ProfilePicture.create({ image: req.file.filename });
      return res.status(200).send({ success: true });
    } catch (error) {
      if (!req.file) {
        return res
          .status(500)
          .render("error/500", { err: "نوع فایل مورد قبول نیست!" });
      }
      console.log(extname(req.file));

      console.log(error);
      return res.status(500).render("error/500", { err: error });
    }
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

I really want to find a way to pass the error to express and not logging it to console with cb().

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `multer` error with an [error-handling middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.error-handling), for example,

```js
router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.render("my_error_page", {error: err});
});
```